# Format mirrored volume in ReFS in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, format, disk-management, refs

I am trying to make a mirrored volume of two drives with the same capacity in Windows 10. I would like to be able to format the drives as ReFS but it is not an option when I try to make a mirror. This is strange because if I try to format one of the drives separately I am able to select ReFS.

The two drives I have is a WD Red and a WD Blue of 6TB each.

How can I make a mirror (like RAID1) with two drives in ReFS?

Comment: Go to ["Storage Spaces in Windows 10"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12438/windows-10-storage-spaces) and look over the section labeled ***"What do I need to create a storage space?"***. Create a **Two-way mirror Storage Space**. Check out ["How to Use Windows 10’s Storage Spaces to Mirror and Combine Drives"](https://www.howtogeek.com/109380/how-to-use-windows-8s-storage-spaces-to-mirror-combine-drives/) as well to help you out a bit for some direction.

Comment: If using Storage Spaces is the only way to achieve this with Windows, then you should add this as an answer. Using Storage spaces worked worked for me and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Storage Spaces in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12438/windows-10-storage-spaces) and look over the "**What do I need to create a storage space?**" labeled section, from there create a **Two-way mirror Storage Space**.

> [**How do I create a storage
>   space?**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12438/windows-10-storage-spaces)
>
> 1. Add or connect the drives that you want to group together with
>      Storage Spaces.
> 2. Go to the taskbar, type **Storage Spaces** in the search box, and select
>      **Storage Spaces** from the list of search results.
> 3. Select **Create a new pool and storage space**.
> 4. Select the drives you want to add to the new storage space, and then
>      select **Create pool**.
> 5. Give the drive a name and letter, and then choose a layout. **Two-way
>      mirror, Three-way mirror**, and **Parity** can help protect the files in
>      the storage space from drive failure.
> 6. Enter the maximum size the storage space can reach, and then select
>      **Create storage space**.

---

### Further Resources

- [Storage Spaces in Windows 10 - Step Details](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12438/windows-10-storage-spaces)
- [How to Use Windows 10’s Storage Spaces to Mirror and Combine Drives](https://www.howtogeek.com/109380/how-to-use-windows-8s-storage-spaces-to-mirror-combine-drives/)
- [Does ReFS replace NTFS? When should I use it?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2013/01/01/windows-server-2012-does-refs-replace-ntfs-when-should-i-use-it/)
- [Windows Storage Spaces and ReFS: Is it time to ditch RAID for good?](https://betanews.com/2014/01/15/windows-storage-spaces-and-refs-is-it-time-to-ditch-raid-for-good/)